# Why is fplot in Matlab mathematically incorrect?

Tags: matlab, plot, symbolic-math, derivative, integral

I am trying to get the derivative and integral of `cos(x/8)*sin(x)`.  Mathematically I know that f(x) should start at 0 and f'(x) should start at 1.  However, my plot in Matlab isn't showing that.

I've tried rearranging the equations and setting upper and lower limits.
[image: code]

```
clc;clear;
syms x f(x) %declaring my symbolic variable
f(x)=cos(x/8)*sin(x);
dfdx=diff(f(x));
ind_ing=int(f(x));
fplot(f(x));
hold on;
fplot(dfdx);
fplot(ind_ing);
hold off
```

Comment: Looking at your plot, I see a function that is 0 at x=0, one that is 1, and one that is -1. Maybe you didn’t notice the x axis values? Are you assuming x=0 is the left edge of the graph?

Comment: I’ve removed the lines of code that don’t have any effect on the plotted figure. This makes it easier to see what you’re doing. You should always minimize your code like this before asking questions about it, as it makes it easier to understand the question and provide an answer. See [mre].

Answer (score -1):

The integral calculation int(f(x)) and the plotting of ind_ing might not be what you expect. The integral of the function should be a function of x, not a single value.

```
clc;
clear;

syms x;

f = cos(x/8) * sin(x);
dfdx = diff(f);

% Calculate the indefinite integral
F = int(f);

% Plot the function, its derivative, and the indefinite integral
fplot(f, [-20, 20]);
hold on;
fplot(dfdx, [-20, 20]);
fplot(F, [-20, 20]);
hold off;

legend('f(x)', "f'(x)", "Indefinite Integral");
title('Plot of f(x), f''(x), and the Indefinite Integral');
```

We calculate the indefinite integral F and then plot it over the same range as the original function and its derivative. This should give you a plot that shows the expected behavior, where the integral starts at 0 and the derivative starts at 1.